# Order of Provider and Router in React app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm making my React app a SPA and adding `React Router 4` with `react-router-dom` to it. Currently, my entry point to my home component looks like this:

```
render (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App>
            <Home />
        </App>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

For another module, I had a different entry point and instead of the `<Home />` component, I'd have a different one but the rest pretty much looked the same.

Two questions:

1. Does it matter if `<BrowserRouter>` should wrap the `<Provider store={store}>` or the other way around? Looks like `react-router-dom` doesn't use the redux store but I still think the `<Provider>` should wrap the `<BrowserRouter>` -- see the code below.
2. I'm also taking the "Home" component out because the router will decide what component to load depending on the URL.

Here's the new code:

```
render (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Am I handling this right?

Comment: 1- No, you don't need using the ```<Provider store={store}>``` if you are not using ```Redux```.


2- If you are using one application with different modules, you don't need define different entry points. As ```react-router``` will manages it for you.

Comment: To clarify my question, I AM using Redux in my app. My question is should it be `<Provider><BrowserRouter><App />` or `<BrowserRouter><Provider><App />`?

Comment: I'm using ```<Provider><BrowserRouter><App />``` in my projects.

Comment: Because, the ```router history``` is managed by ```Redux store```  and is passed down via ```ConnectedRouter```. We need to tell ```react-dom``` to render our application with the correct ```store``` and ```browser history``` data. We do this by using the ```ConnectedRouter``` export given to us by React Router v4. ```ConnectedRouter``` has access to the store given to ```Provider``` so you don’t need to worry about passing data through any additional props.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you need to use history / programmatic route changes from within your provider, that the provider needs to be nested inside the router.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## It does not matter.

They don’t depend on each other.

Take a look at their implementations, specifically at their render methods.

[Redux Provider,](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/Provider.js#L35) [React Router.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Router.js#L78)

They mostly just declare couple of `contextTypes`, and render children.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux'
import store, { history } from './store'
import App from './app'

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <App />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

Comment: Exactly right, using `react-router-redux` is necessary for nested several routes.